# Do we have the following uniform convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

We are given a sequence $f_N$ such that $f_N(x) \xrightarrow{N\to\infty} f(x)$ uniformly in $x$.  $f$ is continuous, but the $f_N$'s are not necessarily continuous. Moreover we know that $y_N = \frac{\lfloor Ny \rfloor}{N} \xrightarrow{N\to\infty} y$, thus also $f_N(y_N) \xrightarrow{N\to\infty} f(y)$ uniformly.
Also given are bounded and smooth functions $\alpha_N$ and $\alpha$ such that $\alpha_N(x) \xrightarrow{N\to\infty} \alpha(x)$ uniformly in $x$. Question: What can we say about the convergence of $f_N(y_N)\alpha(y_N)$? I would think it converges uniformly to $f(y)\alpha(y)$.

Comment: $|f_N(y_N)\alpha(y_N)-f(y)\alpha(y)| = |f_N(y_N)\alpha(y_N) - f_N(y_N)\alpha(y) + f_N(y_N)\alpha(y)-f(y)\alpha(y)| \leq |f_N(y_N)||\alpha(y_N) - \alpha(y)| + |\alpha(y)||f_N(y_N) - f(y)|$

Comment: The second term we can make arbitrarily small as $\alpha$ bounded and $f_N$ converge uniformly to $f$. However for the first term the $f_N(y_N)$ cannot be bounded as it is not know if they are bounded. Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Or do we must have that the $f_N$'s are bounded?, as otherwise we cannot have uniform convergence of the $f_N$'s.

Comment: Hi, you should edit your post adding the three comment above that is you work.

Comment: I don't know if it is the right approach. Thats why I put it as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three points :

- You never mentioned that the convergence of $\alpha_N \to \alpha$ is uniform. I hope so, otherwise you definitely can't get your result.
- Assuming that, you essentially have a correct proof in your comment, except that you don't know whether $f_N(y_N)$ is bounded. But of course it is : $y_N$ is a convergent sequence, so you can find a closed interval $[a,b]$ that contains it. On this interval, $y$ is bounded in absolute value (by say $K$) because it is continuous. Moreover, for $N$ large enough, $|f_n - f| \leq 1 $ because of uniform convergence. Hence on $[a,b]$, $|f_N| \leq K+ 1$ for $N$ large enough. Hence $|f_N(y_N)| \leq 1$ for $N$ large enough.
- You should not say $f_N(x) \xrightarrow{N\to\infty} f(x)$ uniformly. It is meaningless for a convergence of numbers to be uniform. You should say $f_N \xrightarrow{N\to\infty} f$ uniformly. Don't mix up the function $f$ with the number $f(x)$.

Comment: Yess the $\alpha$ do converge uniformly. $f_N$ are functions actually, however I suppose that when evaluated in a certain $x$ you could see it as a sequence of real numbers.

Comment: Sure but uniform convergence of a sequence of real numbers doesn't really mean anything. Or some people also say $f_N(x) \xrightarrow{N\to\infty} f(x)$ **uniformly in $x$**.

Comment: But based on your second comment I think its clear that indeed we can conclude that the $f_N$'s have to be bounded, as otherwise we cannot have uniform convergence to a continuous $f$.

Comment: That's right. Mix in my second point with your work and you've got a proof.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips!